# How to check value of a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, null, segmentation-fault, free

I am coding a program where a pointer `STR *pt` to a `STR` type structure that I am using (basically an array of `STR` structures with which I want to use dynamic memory) might takes a `NULL` value as sometimes I don't want to store any array trough it, so when I use `free(pt)` over that pointer I get a segmentation fault. What I want is to check it that pointer has a `NULL` value, but when I check `if(pt != NULL) free(pt);` (I only want to free memory when pointer is not `NULL`), condition is always true, pointer is tryed to be freed and segmentation fault happens.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Another way to compare pointer values?

Comment: The `free(NULL)` you mention does not cause a fault, it is caused by trying to `free` a pointer whose value was not obtained from `malloc` etc. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest complete code that shows the problem.

Comment: Do you happen to be using a toolchain from the 1990s?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923290/heap-corruption-in-c/3923306#3923306

Comment: Your problem isn't because `pt` is NULL but it's invalid (e.g. heap corruption, you modified the pointer original returned by *alloc, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Your check looks correct; free() should not fail if passed a non-null pointer to a heap-allocated structure.

Where does the value of 'pt' come from? Did you get it from malloc()?

If you have not already, it's probably worth using GDB to verify a NULL pointer here is really causing your problem.

Comment: `free(NULL)` is completely legal and harmless, so the test is useless.

Comment: Hah; I never knew that, but right you are. To be pedantic, I came across this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46825852/6791142 . So I suppose if(pt) should not be relied upon.

Comment: The value of `STR *pt` comes from a memory allocation *in the case it previously happened*, the thing it that in the opposite case I supposed a `NULL` would have been stored. Is there any way to check if a memory allocation has been produced?

Comment: You might be interested in [Is NULL always false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459743/is-null-always-false)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use free() on memory allocated by malloc,calloc or realloc.First you have to assign it some memory then check

```
if(pt)
{
    free(pt)
}
```

Comment: No, you do not have to check if the pointer is not `NULL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I asked OP a question; if he answers yes ...

Comment: (I only want to free memory when pointer is not NULL) according to the user JuanSarraceno

Comment: `free(NULL)` is completely legal and harmless, so the test is useless.

Comment: Yes the test is useless

Comment: @Joshua until the OP posts more detail, it is safe to assume that the problem is pointer mismanagement, or uninitilaised variable etc.

Comment: So, `if(pt)` is true when a memory allocation has happened and false when it doesn't?

Comment: No, it is entirely dependant on your pointer management. When you call `malloc()` etc, you can test the pointer like that to see of the allocation was successful. But given some pointer varaible, there is no way to check if its value came from `malloc`.

Comment: If the value is given by malloc then you can see a decrease of heap memory for your program in debug mode.If you use any static memory heap will not get affected